# set nested div height to 100%

Tags: css, html, height

This has been answered lots of times, but i cannot get the height of a div to be 100%.

All other solutions involve setting html, body and parent div's to `height: 100%`.

I have tried this and it is not working. In the example, it is the `inner_column` div in particular that i am trying to get to be 100% height.

Example code:

html:

```
<div id="outer_column">
    <div id="inner_column">
        <div class="section">
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

#outer_column {
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#inner_column {
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #000000;
    height: 100%;
}

.section{
    padding: 20px;
    background: #cccccc;
    width: 650px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

**update:**  I think it's a cache issue, the above works, thank you.

**update two:**  actually, I am finding now that the height is only the height of the screen and if I add more content the containing div does not span the height of the body, I updated one of the following jsfiddle's: http://jsfiddle.net/Cuzr9/2 - is there a way to make it span the height of the body regardless of how much content there is? thank you.

Comment: You need to be clear about what you want your height to 100% of. By default it will be 100% of whatever height is needed to enclose its contents. If you want it to be 100% of something else you need to say what.

Comment: html,body{ min-height: 100%;} other divs{ height: 100%}

Comment: If you use your code as you have posted I show that `inner_column` is `height:100%`. What makes you think it isn't? http://jsfiddle.net/Cuzr9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V3xWt/ 
everything works OK for me in Firefox

Comment: think it was cache issue, i added another div with position of absolute, refreshed and it worked.  i will indicate that the above works. thank you all for testing.

Comment: You need to define position by default position is static and in static position element you can't define height in percentage. Change it to relative http://jsfiddle.net/Cuzr9/1/

Comment: actually, i am finding now that the height is only the height of the *screen* and if i add more content the containing div does not span the height of the body, i updated one of the following jsfiddle's above:  http://jsfiddle.net/Cuzr9/2/ - is there a way to make it span the height of the *body* regardless of how much content there is?  thank you.

Comment: please close this question or answer it yourself for it to be considered answered